# Finding earliest date by a looping through a json file with common ids

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Im new to python and been trying some projects at home. I have pulled json data from an api and formatted into just the data i want but i need to remove duplicate (id) records with the oldest dates.

my json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2019-06-20T10:39:03.915Z",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2019-06-20T07:50:53.533Z",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2019-06-19T10:55:21.741Z",
    "name": "xxx"
  }, 
]
```

I have tried using (data being my json file):

```
for item in data:
    oldest_time = min(item.get('date'))
    d = {
        'id': item.get('id'),
        'date': oldest_time,
        'name': item.get('name')
    }
    new.append(d)

with open('new.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(new, f, indent=2)
```

I was hoping to get the following output in new.json, however the dates seem to be empty:

```
[ 
  { 
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2019-06-20T07:50:53.533Z",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2019-06-19T10:55:21.741Z",
    "name": "xxx"
  },
]
```

My code may look bad to some but please excuse as ive not been coding with python long. I have looked for similar topics but have not found anything. Any help would be great.

Comment: The json data you have isn't valid JSON format per the [specification](http://json.org/).

Comment: So is `data` a `list` of `dictionary` elements?

Comment: Look into `datetime.strptime(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the data using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. This can be your key for sorting your `list` from oldest record to newest:

```py
import datetime 

data = [{
     "id": 1,
     "date": "2019-06-20T10:39:03.915Z",
     "name": "xxx"
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "date": "2019-06-20T07:50:53.533Z",
     "name": "xxx"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "date": "2019-06-19T10:55:21.741Z",
     "name": "xxx"
   }]

sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))

[{'id': 2, 'date': '2019-06-19T10:55:21.741Z', 'name': 'xxx'}, 
 {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-06-20T07:50:53.533Z', 'name': 'xxx'}, 
 {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-06-20T10:39:03.915Z', 'name': 'xxx'}]
```

If you want newest records first, you just pass the `reverse` keyword to `sorted`:

```py
sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), reverse=True)

[{'id': 1, 'date': '2019-06-20T10:39:03.915Z', 'name': 'xxx'}, 
 {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-06-20T07:50:53.533Z', 'name': 'xxx'}, 
 {'id': 2, 'date': '2019-06-19T10:55:21.741Z', 'name': 'xxx'}
```

Now, you can group your results by `id`, and use the above to grab the oldest record:

```py
# we will use a defaultdict here because it lends itself to this kind of grouping problem
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in data:
    d[item['id']].append(item) # create your lists grouped by id

# d now looks like
#{1: [{'id': 1, 'date': '2019-06-20T10:39:03.915Z', 'name': 'xxx'}, 
#     {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-06-20T07:50:53.533Z', 'name': 'xxx'}], 
# 2: [{'id': 2, 'date': '2019-06-19T10:55:21.741Z', 'name': 'xxx'}]}

# Now, sort and use `pop` to grab the oldest, since the reversed
# option will put the newest date first and the oldest last
for k, v in d.items():
    # v will be lists, sort them using the method above,
    # and pop() will return the last element of the list
    v = sorted(v, key = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), reverse=True).pop()
    d[k] = v

list(d.values())
[{'id': 1, 'date': '2019-06-20T07:50:53.533Z', 'name': 'xxx'}, {'id': 2, 'date': '2019-06-19T10:55:21.741Z', 'name': 'xxx'}]
```

Comment: Thanks C.Nivs I will give that a go. I was trying to creat a new list with only the oldest date for each unique Id

Comment: Thanks @C.Nivs this works great. Really appreciate the replies (now to research and really understand it). Thanks again!!!